# Configure List to create page for each entry based on template

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Is it possible, to configure a sharepoint list to create a page for each new entry that is added to the list? If so, how?

Ideally, the page should be based on a custom page template.

Background/Use case (for the case, that there is a better approach than a list):
Our company wants to set up a list of all our machines (about 200). There should be list of all machines available that can be filtered/sorted. Also, for each machine a details page, where additional information like like service sheets, commants, documents aso are stored.

I thought that a combination of list and pages would be a good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Power Automate flow to automatically create a page.

Create an automated flow triggered when an item is created and "add send an HTTP request to SharePoint action".

For Reference:

[Automate Modern SharePoint Page Creation Using Power Automate](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/automate-modern-sharepoint-page-creation-using-power-automate)

[SPO Modern Page Creation using Power Automate](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/SPO-Modern-Page-Creation-using-Power-Automate/td-p/695720)

Comment: Sounds good. For now I'll try if a websitepages library with additional columns will get me there.